# How to Delete a single file from media store?

Tags: android, mysql

This code works

```
getActivity().getContentResolver().
   delete(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTEN‌​T_URI ,
          "TITLE ='" + songdetails.get(index).song + "'", null);
```

but the problem is, it will delete all the files with the given title. I tried **DATA** instead of **TITLE** but it didn't work an error pops up saying "No column named DATA".

Can anyone give any suggestion on what to be  use instead of title? Or can any one tell me totally different way to delete something. I also tried,  which works ,

```
File file = new File(songdetails.get(index).Path);
                 boolean deleted = file.delete();
```

but the problem with this is mediastore doesn't get updated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this line after delete function

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

(above solution doesn't seem to work since android 4.4)

for DATA :

```
MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA
```

also you can try using this

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(fileDeleted)));
```

see this link for a (kind of) detailed method:

http://sandersdenardi.com/querying-and-removing-media-from-android-mediastore/

also keep in mind that:

> All queries and deletes (and inserts and updates for that matter)
>   block until the underlying transaction completes. You should perform
>   these operations on the ContentResolver asynchronously on a separate
>   thread. While a delete on the MediaStore shouldn’t take a significant
>   amount of time at all, it will block the UI if performed on the main
>   thread.

Comment: Why should i ??this will rescan the whole external storage,giving a 2-3 seconds lag...

Comment: That to this will not work in android 4.4.throws securityException

Comment: sorry as it will not work in 4.4 i have accepted kalyan's answer

Comment: actually only the first solution will not work in 4.4, MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILR would work with 4.4 and also the solution provided in the link.

Answer (score 5):

Do something like this..to scan your file..Just pass the file path you want to delete..

```
private void scanaddedFile(String path) {
    try {
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, new String[] { path },
                null, new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                        context.getContentResolver()
                                .delete(uri, null, null);
                    }
                });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: check out gaurav's answer ,its a one liner but anyways thanx +1

Comment: guys, the other solutions i suggested, specifically the ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE works with 4.4

Comment: @kalyanpvs you might have won the Marauder hat :P (steal a checkmark) http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/

Comment: click on the snowflake icon near the achievements icon on the top menu and click i love hats

Comment: This method is quite easy to follow and requires very little learning. The code may be easily generalised and used to both add and remove files from media library. One small note: in my case, files need to be removed from media library **before** they get physically removed using e.g. File.delete. Otherwise `context.getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);` throws `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 0):

```
getActivity().getContentResolver().delete(
   MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTEN‌​T_URI ,
   MediaStore.MediaColumns.Data + " = ?", 
    new String[] { fileName });
```

The value of `MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA` is `"_data"`.