# How to delete a file using uri in android

Tags: android, android-file

I am new to android app development and i am building a music player app. I am querying songs using Content Resolver. I want to implement a feature to delete the song permanently from the device. I am using the following code but unable to achieve it.

```
Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,song.getId());

        File file = new File(uri.getPath());

        if(file.delete()){
            Log.d("MUSIC SERVICE DELETE","SUCCESS");
        }
        else {
            Log.d("MUSIC SERVICE DELETE","FAILED");
        }
```

Comment: You cannot use the File class for your uri. And you did not tell if you are on Android Q or lower. Have a look here for a start: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20719198/how-to-delete-a-single-file-from-media-store

Comment: I am on android R or lower. In that post MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA is used which is deprecated right and using ContentResolver.delete(uri,null,null) is not deleting  the file.

Comment: If you have the uri then you do not need the .DATA column for a delete. On Q+ there is .RELATIVE_PATH. But that you dont need either to delete an uri.

Comment: On Q+ delete from MediaStore is all you have to do. Below Q you have to delete the file itself too (using .DATA indeed i think).

Comment: I want to delete the physical file in the file system

Comment: In the link you provided they are using getContentResolver.delete(uri,null,null) which is only deleting the database entry but not the file in the storage

Comment: Under Q it should delete both. You are not even mentioning if that is on Q or not.

Comment: I have used getContentResolver.delete(uri,null,null)and tested in android P device the file is onlydeleted in database but it is still showing in folder

Comment: Sorry for not understanding your comment properly I got it now.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out how to do it thanks to the comments by blackapps.
This is the code i used to implement delete

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        Song song = songsSet.get(songPosition);
        Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,songsSet.get(songPosition).getId());
        if(contentResolver.delete(uri,null,null) > 0){
            Log.d("DATABASE DELETE","SUCCESS");

            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.Q){
                File file = new File(song.getData());
                if(file.delete()){
                    Log.d("DELETE","SUCCESS");
                }
                else {
                    Log.d("DELETE","FAILED");
                }
            }

            songsSet.remove(song);
        }
        else {
            Log.d("DATABASE DELETE","FAILED");
        }
```

In android Q you cannot use `DATA` in `MediaStore`and using `ContentResolver.delete()` deletes both ContentProvider entry and File.